# What is RoleAssignment, RoleDefinition, RoleBinding in Sharepoint On-premise? How to remove a user from the permission list at site level?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, csom

I'm struggling with removing permission with the User type (not Sharepoint group type) at the site level but I'm struggling with these terms to find solutions.
When I open the central admin site, in the SITE PERMISSIONS section, I can find these

**Name                             Type                  Permission Levels**

Delegated Administrator          Sharepoint group      Contribute

Farm Administrator               Sharepoint group      Full control

Nash Saluah                      User                  Full control

Talulah Lin                      User                  Full control

I want to remove Nash and Talulah from this list but cannot find any solution for it.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some detailed screenshots of the description, I didn't find the SITE PERMISSIONS section in CA and a couple of Name Type Permission Levels you mentioned.

Comment: @Xyza_MSFT I've added a screenshot. I think you can find SITE PERMISSIONS in the site setting, under the USERS AND PERMISSIONS category.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in your screenshot, I don't see the Delegated administrator Sharepoint group contribution ,Farm Administrator Sharepoint Group Full Control,Nash Saluah user Full control,Talulah Lin user Full control you mentioned!